# If u > 0 is any real number and x < y, show that there exists a rational number r such that x < ru < y

Tags: real-analysis

If $u > 0$ is any real number and $x < y$, show that there exists a rational number $r$ such that $x < ru < y$.

Since $u > 0$ and $x < y$, then we know that $x/u<y/u$.

By the Density Theorem, we know there exists $r \in\mathbb Q$ such that $x/u<r<y/u$.

We finish the proof by multiplying the inequalities by $u$.

Is this enough for the proof?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: $f_u(x)=ux$ is surjective from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb Q$ is dense, so....